# Phonegap how would i have the same layout(zoom level) for high/medium dpi devices?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I read that the target-densitydpi is deprecated in Android and will be in IOS.

I am wondering for Phonegap/Cordova, how would i go about having the same layout for medium and high def devices? At the moment my high def devices has the correct layout, for the medium dpi devices, everythings too big.

Or would i have to set media queries for every element that i would want to have different layout? something like the below?

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 15/10)
{
  body { font-size:150%; } /* provide high-res image */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend https://github.com/biodiv/cordova-screengod . Instead of media queries, you write one css file, which is then adapted to any screen on startup with

```
screengod(['path/to/your.css'],function(){
    /* do your app stuff */
});
```

after the deviceready event. Media queries just eat up hours of time and do not work well enough as there are too many screen specs out there with new ones emerging all the time - and there are conflicts across android versions.